# Installation of Rsyslog on Centos 7

Tags: centos, rsyslog

I need to install rsyslog on a CentOS 7 host. I have been trying to do so using the command "yum install rsyslog" but haven't been successful in doing so.
The system does not even give a proper error to work upon, rather it says "Package rsyslog.x86_64 0:8.24.0-34.el7 will be installed". Here is output what it says upon running the installation command "yum install rsyslog":

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package rsyslog.x86_64 0:8.24.0-34.el7 will be installed
Removing rsyslog.x86_64 0:8.24.0-34.el7 - u due to obsoletes from installed si-syslog-1.0-13.el7.x86_64
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package rsyslog.x86_64 0:8.24.0-34.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
```

The link I followed for this purpose is: https://qradarinsights.com/2018/11/27/using-syslog-ng-to-monitor-and-forward-log-files-to-qradar/

Can anyone please help with a way around this..?

Comment: What is that package `si-syslog` that you have previously installed?

Comment: I am not sure about this. I tried looking for it but didn't find anything meaningful.. May be this referes to syslog-ng that comes presintalled on CentOS.

Comment: syslog-ng doesn't come preinstalled on CentOS. No syslog daemon does. In any case, it's called syslog-ng, not si-syslog. Did someone else set up that system? Did they leave documentation? Do they still work there, that you might have a chat with them?